# callback to addclass on jQuery

Tags: jquery

I wrote the following which change the background of the even rows when the user clicks the button, I want to add a callback function that removes the class, how can I do that?

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=TlsqQVlA23

```
 $("#hideshow").click(function(){
       $("tr:even").toggle("3500",function(){
            $("tr").addClass("red");
        });
    });
```

I tried

```
 $("#hideshow").click(function(){
           $("tr:even").toggle("3500",function(){
                $("tr").addClass("red");
            },function(){
                $("tr").removeClass("red");
            });
        });
```

But there is an error on the console.

Comment: What error? You need to add more detail if you want help.

Comment: Please make a regular fiddle, collaboration is too confusing.

Comment: It's also not useful for future readers of the question when you link to a collaboration, since it will change by the time they read it.

Comment: It seems like you should just be using `toggleClass`, not `toggle`, since you don't want to hide and show things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to add/remove `red` class `#hideshow` is clicked, try this:

```
$("#hideshow").click(function(){
           $("tr:even").toggleclass("red");
        });
```

this will hide/show red class

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to change the class for the each row - you can change the class only for `table`. This will works **much faster** than coloring each particular row. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jslayer/RN9AP/

CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.zebra tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
}
```

JS:

```
var $table = $('table');

$('#toggle').click(function(){
    $table.toggleClass('zebra')
})
```